# How to filter empty key/value pairs from a $_POST array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create php array (associative) declaration for non-empty key-value pairs only, which I am getting from $_POST. Any guesses, how to do this ?

```
$my_array = [

"k1"=>"$val1",
"k2"=>"$val2",
"k3"=>"$val3",
"k4"=>"$val4"

];
```

But, if $val4 & $val3 are empty / NULL / does'nt exist, then :

```
$my_array = [

"k1"=>"$val1",
"k2"=>"$val2"

];
```

Thanks

Comment: u can try `array_filter()`

Comment: Keys are not coming from $_POST as field-names, they are custom.

Comment: Thanks for DOWNVOTES..

Comment: No no I am not the down voter , I suggest u the solution

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you can use array filter,

if you dont want values of `0` being treated as empty you can do something like this

```
$post = array_filter( $_POST, function( $item ){ return strlen( $item ); });
```

Array filter will treat `0`, `''`, `false`, `null` and I think `'0'` and possibly some others all as empty.  You can use a callback, such as my example. When the call back returns false `0` the item is removed when it returns true ( or > 0 ) it is retained.  So strlen will return a value equal to the length of the string and any strings of `0` length are then removed.

-note- this should be fine on $_POST because it's generally not going to have any nested arrays, but if there are nested arrays then strlen will obviously not work on an array ( being this `$item = array()` in the callback ).

Comment: Keys are not coming from $_POST as field-names, they are custom.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is already an associative array. For example, with a form, the key is the element 'name' and the value is the user's input. Empty inputs will still generate a key/value pair but you can easily filter these with [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

EDIT:

Here is an example implementation:

```
array_filter($array, function(x) { 
    if is_null(x) return false;
    else return true;
});
```

Comment: you should mention what array filter treats as empty, `0` may not be what they want to consider as this `''`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix array_filter() treats 0 as you tell it to because array_filter() uses a callback method to define what is filtered and what is not.

Comment: Keys are not coming from $_POST as field-names, they are custom.

Comment: Regardless of the keys, `array_filter()` will iterate over every array entry and do what you want with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function to check null or empty values like this:

```
<?php

function transform(&$data) {
    foreach(array_keys($data) as $key) {
        if( is_null($data[$key]) 
            || empty($data[$key]) 
        ) {
            unset($data[$key]);
        } 
    }
}

// usage
$data = [
    "example1" => 5,
    "example2" => "some text",
    "example3" => null,
    "example4" => [],
];

transform($data);

print_r($data);

?>
```

Example output of print_r() :

```
Array
(
    [example1] => 5
    [example2] => some text
)
```

Comment: As stated in the 2 answers previous, `array_filter()` is a function that already allows implementation of what you are suggesting. No need to re-write it.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart Thanks for inputs..i didnt re-write anything :)